# MODIS land surface temperature range very high

Tags: geospatial, google-earth-engine, satellite-image

I have been trying to use [MODIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderate_Resolution_Imaging_Spectroradiometer) ([MOD11A1.006](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod11a1v006/) Terra Land Surface Temperature and Emissivity Daily Global 1 km).

The LST, but in MODIS, the range of temperature is too high and is not starting from 0 °C (273 K) or -ve value. The range is as shown below:

**LST_Day_1km        7500-65535 Kelvin**              Daytime Land Surface Temperature

How can I correct this to obtain a correct range?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [band information page for this dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD11A1#bands), it lists a 'scale' value of 0.02 of the LST_Day_1km band. This indicates images should be multiplied by 0.02 to get the correct value in kelvin.